# Conditional in Mason code

Tags: html, perl, mason

If I want to create a block of html code that displays if a boolean value in mason is true is there a way to do this without using print to print each line of the html code?  i.e. is there a way to do something like this

```
<% if($boolean) { %>
<li>
<a href='http://somesite.com'>link</a>
</li>
<% } %>
```

instead of

```
<%perl>
if($boolean) {
print "<li>";
print "<a href='http://somesite.com'>link</a>";
print "</li>";
}
</%perl>
```

Comment: I found out the way to do this for anyone interested is by using % at the start of the line instead of surrounding the conditional start and end with <% %>.   I'm posting answer in comments because I am a new user and need to wait 8 hours before answering my own question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mention in your comment, you can:

```
% if($boolean) {
<li>
<a href='http://somesite.com'>link</a>
</li>
% }
```